# MVC dropdownlist with dynamic custom parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a list of objects say Employee, and I am trying to get the dropdown list of all employee names with a custom parameter with their employee id. The Model is as follows

```
public class Emp
{
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
    public int employeeId {get;set;}
}
```

I am looking to create a Dropdownlist with HTML.DropdownlistFor as below

```
<select>
<option employeeid="101"> Emp1 <option>
<option employeeid="102"> Emp2 <option>
<option employeeid="103"> Emp3 <option>
</select>
```

Comment: You cannot. The `@HtmlDropDownListFor()` method use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `SelectListItem` does not have have a property for `employeeid`. Why do you thing you need this as an attribute of `<option>`? (there are numerous other ways to handle this)

Comment: Hi Draken, I have a product with already available script library built on custom attributes and have to re-use them. we normally add class attribute and other static attributes to the syntax, I was just wondering if we can even make it dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is invalid, a `<select>` tag does not have an attribute called employeeid. Since you're clearly trying to bind the employeeId to a the *value* of an option, you should use the classic `name` and `value` attributes which can be used as follows:

```
<select name="employeeid">
    <option value="101">Gary</option>
    <option value="102">John</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

Now in your controller action in your MVC project, you recieve a parameter called employeeid which is of the type `int`. The *model binder* (look it up) will automatically bind the value you selected in the 'employeeid' select input element when you submit the form.

The answer @daniell89 provided shows you a nice way of populating your select tag using the [Razor template language](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp) pretty much everyone uses for c# MVC projects. Note how a `ViewModel` you use in your `view` does not have to be the same as the `ViewModel` you submit to the action you post to, so the `public int SelectedEmployee { get; set; }` is actually not necessary in the `ViewModel`, as long as you have the 'employeeid' as a parameter for the action you submit to.

## EDIT

In order to use custom attributes you will kind of have to move away from classic MVC, because the post you will do will be done by an AJAX Post. You will need to import the jQuery library (actually you can use vanilla javascript or any library of your choosing, I prefer jQuery for this kind of stuff), look up how to import this if you need to.

Use a ViewModel in your code alike this:

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this model in your view as such (first line of code of your view, unless you have using statements):

`@model IEnumerable<Employee>`

Then right at the place you want to have your select button create this code:

```
<select id="my-select-element">
@foreach(var employee in Model) {
    <text>
         <option employeeid="@employee.EmployeeId">@employee.Name</option>
    </text>
}
</select>

<button id="submit-employee">Send!</button>
```

This will create your select tag with all the employees you've put in your viewmodel, together with a button you will use to send your data to your server.

Then include the following jQuery script on your page, that will collect your data and send it to the server.

```
<script>
     $("#submit-employee").on("click", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); //will prevent default behaviour done by clicking the button
         var selecttag = $("#my-select-element");
         var id = $(selecttag).find("option").prop("selected").attr("employeeid");

         $.post("<your URL>", { employeeid: id }, function(result) {
              console.log(result);
         }
     }
</script>
```

Then in your controller on your server code, have an action corresponding with  and have it parameterised with an `int emplyeeid` as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitEmployee (int employeeid) {
     return new Json().Body(new { message = "I saw " + employeeid })
}
```

If all goes right, your console window in your browser will be showing you a returned object that has a 'message' key with a value 'I saw 101' if you selected 101 as the employee before sending it.

I typed all this code right in the stackoverflow editor, so I may have made some syntax errors or mistakes in the way types are called (Im not sure if you can just do new Json().Body() for instance, though I know you can do something similar for sure.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Glubus. Appreciate you trying to clarify the cases which should be used. But I have already used the value and I need to use custom attributes.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that you can use custom attributes, though you must realise that this is not following the MVC standard. Actually custom attributes inherently are not in according with MVC when it comes to communication between server and client.

Comment: Thanks Glubus, I had already achieved this using custom code, just wanted to know if I was missing something to achieve it using the standard HTML Helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another class- EmpViewModel:

```
public class EmpViewModel
{
    public int SelectedEmployee { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can pass instance of this class to the view and create dropdown list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEmployee, new SelectList(Model.EmployeeList, "employeeId", "EmployeeName"));
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but this drop down would not have any custom attributes. Its just a select value / display option.